# Using powershell to read text files, Edit a Column before outputting each text file to a CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, text

I've got a batch of text files that need to be converted to csv files. However, once I open the csv file, the data in a column has been converted to scientific notation. I want to prevent this by editing the column and inserting an apostrophe before outputting to the final csv. Most of the suggestions I found online involve defining all the columns/headers first. This solution is not ideal, as different text files have different headers. However, all files will have a Column named "acct". This is the only column I am looking to edit.

My Script for taking the text and outputting to csv:

```
$path = "C:\Test\*.txt"
$files = Get-ChildItem $path | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }
foreach ($file in $files){
    $newFileName = ($file.Fullname) -Replace ".txt",".csv"
    Import-Csv $file.FullName |Export-Csv $newFileName -NoTypeInformation 
}
```

So far, I've been able to edit the Columns like so

```
    $acct = (Import-Csv $file).acct
    $acct ="'"+ $acct
```

I'm struggling to combine these so that my output, $newfilename, has the edited value stored in the "acct" column. Any and all advice is welcomed, if there's another way to convert these files and prevent data turning into scientific notation, I'm all for it.

When I've tried to combine my code, for example by piping $acct to to export-csv, usually the output I end up with is a csv file that only has the following content:
"Length"
"34"
EDIT: I'm updating with a sample of the data I'm dealing with. The original file contains 167 Columns, which I don't think I can post here in a way that is legible.

> data_id,place,placepool_id,acct,sec_acct,ter_acct,source_acct,product_id
> 123A0001234567,00,12345,1234567890123456,9876543210123456,,,123,

> 123A0001234567,00,12345,1.23457E+15,9.87654E+15,,,123,

I wanted to edit the data to prevent any info from being converted to scientific notation.

Comment: "However, once I open the csv file" - with what application? In Excel you'll likely have to use the data import wizard to avoid the automatic conversions, or use something like ImportExcel

Comment: The problem is 100% that excel does the automatic conversions. I wanted to put together a script in order to avoid using the import wizard. The simplest way as far as I could tell is by inserting an apostrophe in front of the number.

Comment: Use with Export-CSV the option UseQotes so when you read into excel it doesn't convert.

Comment: I'm using Powershell 5.1, unfortunately UseQuotes is not an available parameter

Comment: Can you open the original csv in notepad and copy the first few lines (including the header row) into your question, and then show what they should look like after the script has run?

Comment: [1] Append `-UseCuture` switch to the Export-Csv command. That way, the csv will have delimiter characters your Excel expects, so you can double-click the csv to have it open in Excel without the Import Wizard. [2] If you do not want to have Excel changing numeric values and instead read these as text, prepend a TAB character ``"`t"`` in front of that value. (not an apostrophe) [3] Show us an example of such a text file so we can be more helpful. ([edit] your post and paste it in there)

Comment: Sorry, typo in [1] `-UseCuture` should be `-UseCulture`

Comment: @Theo I added in a small sample of what the file looks like, the full file has 150+ Columns but only the first few are affected by this issue. In my example two columns were converted to scientific but I only NEED the "acct" column to remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment:

- to stop Excel from converting your numeric values when imoprting the data, you can prepend a TAB character in front of its value. Excel will then read it as text
- When saving the updated data using `Export-Csv` you can append switch `-UseCulture`so  the delinmiter character used is choden from whatever character is set as your local ListSeparator character. Excel expects that when opening the file by double-click so you don't have to use the Import Wizard.
  (to see what character is set in your system, use `(Get-Culture).TextInfo.ListSeparator`)

```
$path = 'C:\Test'
$files = Get-ChildItem $path -File -Filter '*.txt'
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $data = Import-Csv -Path $file.FullName
    foreach ($row in $data) {
        # prepend a TAB character in front of the field you want Excel to 
        # treat as string as opposed to converting it to scientific value
        $row.acct = "`t{0}" -f $row.acct
        # you can do the same here for fields 'data_id', 'sec_acct' etc if needed
    }
    $newFile = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($file.Fullname,".csv")
    # now save the updated data. With -UseCulture you can simply
    # double-click the created csv file to open in Excel on any machine
    # that has the same locale setting for the ListSeparator
    $data | Export-Csv -Path $newFile -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
}
```

Comment: Finally back from vacation and this was a welcome sight. This got the job done!

Answer (score 1):

So you had the right idea with editing the column using the name. We just need to do this by row to edit each value. We are also able to get [column names](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-retrieve-csv-file-headers-using-powershell) thankfully so it should work without having to manually type all the columns out. I used [@Theo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) recommendation to pre-append "`t" to the cell value which fixes the issue of excel showing the values in scientific notation.

Hopefully this is a good starting point. It might not be the most efficient in its current state.

```
$path = "C:\Test\*.txt"
$files = Get-ChildItem $path | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }
foreach ($file in $files){
    $newFileName = ($file.Fullname) -Replace ".txt",".csv"
    $csv = Import-Csv $file.FullName

    # get column names
    $columnNames = ($csv[0].psobject.Properties | select Name).Name

    # will have to work by row
    $rowNum = [int]0
    while ($rowNum -lt $csv.count){
        
        # on the row change value for each column
        foreach ($column in $columnNames) {
    
            
            $csv[$rowNum].$column = "`t" +  $csv[$rowNum].$column
        }
        
        $rowNum += 1
    }

    
    # was running into a bug with powershell on a mac so had to pipe $csv to export-csv instead of using -input-object
    $csv | Export-Csv -LiteralPath $newFileName -NoTypeInformation
    
}
```

Comment: This also works! As a bonus, I also learned how to efficiently get the column names thanks to your reply, which will definitely come in handy in the future.